# Compare columns from two dataframes when values don't match exactly

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, like this:

```
In [2]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'qux', 'baz'],
   ...:                     'name': ['apple', 'bird', 'apple', 'bird', 'car', 'car', 'bird'],
   ...:                     'value': [999, 1103, 1070, 1210, 1521, 1622, 1550]})

In [3]: df1
Out[3]:
  item   name  value
0  foo  apple    999
1  foo   bird   1103
2  bar  apple   1070
3  bar   bird   1210
4  bar    car   1521
5  qux    car   1622
6  baz   bird   1550
```

and

```
In [4]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'qux'],
   ...:                     'size': [1076, 1266, 1380, 1620],
   ...:                     'total': [5, 10, 5, 13]})

In [5]: df2
Out[5]:
  item  size  total
0  foo  1076      5
1  foo  1266     10
2  bar  1380      5
3  qux  1620     13
```

I'd like to examine `df2.size`, compare it to the `df1.value`, then add the corresponding `df1.name` to df2.

The kicker is that `df1.value` and `df2.size` are rarely an exact match; instead, I want the closest `df1.value` that is *less* than (or equal to) the `df2.size` value.  Put another way, referring to df1 above, in the "foo" item group, anything between the values of 999 and 1102 are a part of the "apple" group, and anything above 1103 would be part of the "bird" group.

Also, `item` needs to match between dataframes.  In other words, a `size` entry from df2 that is classified as a "foo" `item` should only be compared to "foo"s in df1.

My desired output is something like:

```
  item   name  size  total
0  foo  apple  1076      5
1  foo   bird  1266     10
2  bar   bird  1380      5
3  qux    NaN  1620     13
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might approach this problem?

One approach I could take would be to `pd.concat` the dataframes, then sort on `['item', 'value']`, then `ffill` the `name` column, then filter where `size` is not null.  But the problem would be that in some cases I would be forward filling across `item` groups, which would lead to spurious results.

Comment: Is this simply a table join on item with some filtering,  sorting and more filtering?

Comment: That's sorta what I was alluding to in my last paragraph-- indeed, it may be that that is the best way to do this.  Though, I was kind of hoping there would be some pandas magic out there that could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've yet to test this on a larger scale, but at Paul's suggestion I've accomplished what I was trying to achieve on the sample dataset I provided.

First step was to rename `df2.size` to `value` just to simplify the `pd.concat`:

```
df2.rename(columns={'size':'value'}, inplace=True)
```

Then concatenate the dataframes, and sort the new frame by item and value:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).sort(['item', 'value'])
```

Next step was to replace the `df3.name` column with a forward-filled groupby series:

```
df3['name'] = df3.groupby(['item'])['name'].ffill()
```

Last step was to filter out the rows where `df3.total` was null:

```
df3[pd.notnull(df3.total)]
```

Comment: This solution does work (though admittedly it is slightly clunky) so it seems like the "answers" section is where it should go.    If someone else has a better way, though,  I'd still love to hear it!